# Passing Dynamic Data to Jquery Event Handler

Tags: jquery

I am attaching an event on page load. The data I pass should come from a text-box. But I guess only the initial value gets retained every time the event is triggered.

```
    $(function(){
        $("#txtInput").on("change",
            {msg:$("#txtInput").val()},myFunc
        );

        function myFunc(event) {
            alert(event.data.msg);
        }
    })

<input id="txtInput"  value="test"/>
```

Every time on change is triggered , it uses "test" as the data. I have tried a lot of things- Calling a function that returns a value of the text-box, using live, on etc. but nothing seems to be working. I think closures could be the answer, but can't seem to come up with anything.

Comment: Not seen that syntax before, but I've had a little read of the docs. Passing the element to the function seems to work -- is that an option? http://jsfiddle.net/k26pd/3/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#txtInput").on("change",function(){

alert($(this).val());

})
```

**Updated**

```
  $("#yourButtonId").on("click",function(){

    alert($("#txtInput").val());

    });
```

Comment: This works . But you know I am facing a more general problem. I have a button and I am attaching the click event to it. The data I need to pass to the handler comes from a text box. How do I get the current value of the text box for the handler ?

Comment: please see this:http://jsfiddle.net/C9GdK/       I cannot use an anonymous function. Need to pass the current value to the method(which is not really an alert and is more complicated). But somehow the current value is not fetched. Thanks for helping tough.

Comment: what you wana do you want to pass that text value to another function?

Comment: yeah! the current value of the text box

Comment: so what is the problem you can get the value by val() function and pass to any

Answer (score 0):

I think this code suits your needs:

```
$('input').on("keyup", function(){
    alert($('input').val());
});
```

Comment: please see this:http://jsfiddle.net/mayurarora/k26pd/      I cannot use an anonymous function. Need to pass the current value to the method(which is not really an alert and is more complicated). But somehow the current value is not fetched. Thanks for helping tough.

Comment: Unfortunately I see nothing by this link

Comment: that works , but I could not find a way to pass the current value in the data map